# Vim plugin to enclose selected text in quotes/parentheses

Tags: vim, plugins

Are there any vim plugins to enclose selected text in quotes or parentheses? For instance, if I were to select a block of text in visual mode, and pressed a key combination or do a command, that text would be enclosed in parentheses/quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) for this type of thing.  For example, visually select an area and type "`\s(`" and the visually selected text will be enclosed in parenthesis.  Change the ( to a double quote and it will use quotes instead.

Unfortunately surround has some slightly odd behaviors, and the help file is sometimes a little unclear, but I find it tolerable.

Answer (score 0):

I've been maintaining a plugin that offers this kind of feature: [lh-map-tools](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhBrackets#The_bracketing_subsystem). You'll have to tune it though to specify bracket-like pairs you want to support.